# How may I fix this search engine entry for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I have a search engine config:

[image]

using the address http://web.archive.org/save/%s , but this use:

[image]

fails thus:

[image]

whereas without the http:// it succeeds.

What modification can I make to the search engine config to remedy this fail, EDIT: else what modification to the Chrome config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't address this problem just using Chromes Custom Search Engines feature. Its too basic.

Instead, download [Switcheroo Redirector Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switcheroo-redirector/cnmciclhnghalnpfhhleggldniplelbg?hl=en)

Now add a Switcheroo rule which maps

```
http://web.archive.org/save/http%3A//  => http://web.archive.org/save/
```

After that, you can type

```
'an http://dell.com'
```

and Chrome will take you to

```
http://web.archive.org/save/http://dell.com
```

Comment: Thanks. I added a second rule for https://. Though this doesn't meet the originally stated requirements, I've relaxed them to accommodate this as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, Switcheroo isn't perfect, but I've not found anything better. It seems to stop as soon as it hits the first rule, but there's no way to reorder them. I wish it supported regular expressions